# How to get right address with multiple "show on map" buttons on javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, innerhtml

I'm making website where I bring information about multiple events using XHR (Ajax) call. Every event has information like name, address and city. I'm listing all these events using innerHTML. Every event has button "show on map" which puts marker to that event's address and shows it on the google map. My problem is that every time I press "show on map" button on any event, it puts marker of the last event's address into a map. I can't figure out right way to make it work so it uses right address and not always the last one. I currently have 10 events (since info.length is 10) but all 10 buttons make the marker in the same place. All help is appreciated!

Here's how I do it:

```
function bringInfo() {

  var info = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

  for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {

    header = info[i].title;
    description = info[i].description;
    address = info[i].contact_info.address;
    city = info[i].contact_info.city;
    link = info[i].contact_info.link;
    pic = info[i].image.src;

    makeEvent(header,description,address,city,link,pic);
  }
}
```

Function where I make event with InnerHTML:

```
function makeEvent(header, description, address, city, link, pic) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var containerElem = document.getElementById('container');

  var eventHTML = "<div class = 'panel'> <h1 id ='header'>" + header + "</h1>" + 
                   "<img src = '" + pic + "'>" +
                   "<p>" + description + "</p>" +
                   "<p>Address:" + address +"</p>" + 
                   "<p>City:" + city +"</p>" + 
                   "<p>Link: <a href ='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a></p>" +  
                   "<button onclick ='geocodeAddress(address)'>Show on map" + "</button>"; 

  newDiv.innerHTML = eventHTML;
  newDiv.className += "panel";
  containerElem.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

EDIT:

```
var myMap;

function geocodeAddress(address) {

 var coder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

 coder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       myMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
       putMarker (results[0].geometry.location, address);
  } else {
     alert('Geocoding didnt work. Reason: ' + status);
  }
  });
  }

function putMarker(p, text) {
   var ownMarker =
   new google.maps.Marker({
      position: p,
      map: myMap,
      title: text
  });
  }
function initMap() {

   myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: 33.33, lng: 33.33},
   zoom: 15
  });
}
```

Comment: is the function called `makeEvent` or `showEvent`?

Comment: Function is called `makeEvent`. Looks like there is typo on first code, it's suppose to be `makeEvent` and not `showEvent`. Let me edit it.

Comment: I don't see any error in those two functions but I suspect the problem is in `geocodeAddress`. Could you show its code ?

Comment: Ok, I edited google maps functions to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change this part:

```
"<button onclick ='geocodeAddress(address)'>Show on map" + "</button>"
```

to

```
"<button onclick ='geocodeAddress(\"' + address + '\")'>Show on map" + "</button>"
```

Currently your onclick event calls geocodeAddress() function with value of the global variable address. The global variable address contains the value for last element in your for loop.